# GitHub Actions PR workflow development routine

Tags: github-actions

I'm working on GitHub actions that only get triggered by `pull_request` events.
Wondering if there is a better "dev experience" than what I'm currently doing.

My understanding is that the workflow file must be in the `base` branch. So in order to test workflow changes, I gotta push code to the base branch, then trigger the workflow via the head branch.

Assume I've already got `my-base` and `my-head` branches, with a pull request set up. I trigger the workflow via `syncronization` events, by pushing to the head branch:

```
git checkout my-base
git add . && git commit -m "plx work" && git push
git checkout my-head
git merge my-base --no-edit && git push
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: That's not true for the trigger `pull_request`. It is enough for this trigger to be on the branch associated with your pull request -- no need to put it in the base branch. `pull_request_target`, however, needs to be in the base branch to name an example.

Comment: Yup, thats work. Thank you. Happy to accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not true for the trigger `pull_request`. It is enough for this trigger to be on the branch associated with your pull request -- no need to put it in the base branch.

`pull_request_target`, however, needs to be in the base branch to name an example. –